# How to combine multiple Markdown sources in a Nunjkucks template in Eleventy

Tags: markdown, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm working with Nunjucks templates in Eleventy. The page layout consists of a main `content` area and an `aside`. I am able to use Markdown for the content but cannot find a way to use Markdown for the aside. It would seem that only one source can be Markdown; any other sources included in the template must be Nunjucks templates.

index.njk:

```
  <article>
    {{ content | safe }} 
  </article>
  <aside>
    {% include "aside.md" %}
  </aside>
```

aside.md:

```
# Aside.
```

Result:

```
<article>
<p>This is the content from the upstream Markdown.</p>
</article>
<aside>
# Aside.
</aside>
```

The aside is still raw Markdown. How can I include processed Markdown?

I'm new to all these technologies and have a feeling I am missing something basic.

Comment: There is a discussion of same problem in 11ty bug tracker, with some solutions proposed. https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/658

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov That solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I incorporate Multiple Markdown files into a Nunjucks template with Eleventy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404330/how-do-i-incorporate-multiple-markdown-files-into-a-nunjucks-template-with-eleve)

Answer (score 0):

Use **includes** or **macros**!

**Includes** have to be placed in a **specific folder** (_includes - you can override this folder name, or even have **sub-folders**):

```
    {% include 'partials/google-analytics.html' %}
    {% include 'partials/cookie-consent.html' %}
    {% include 'partials/post-sharing.html' %}
```

Or you can define a **macro** (they have to be imported, or be defined where you use them). The PRO for macros is that you can pass in **parameters** when you call them, **they work as functions**...

```
{% macro paginationLink(active, disabled, href, title) %}    
    <li class="page-item {% if active %} active {% elseif disabled %} disabled {% endif %}">
        {% if disabled %} 
            <span class="page-link">{{ title | safe }}</span>
        {% else %}
            <a class="page-link" href="{{ href | url }}">{{ title | safe }}</a>
        {% endif %}        
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

The macro ^ can then be easily called:

```
{{ paginationLink(false, isFirst, firstPageHref, '<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>') }}
```