# How do I incorporate Multiple Markdown files into a Nunjucks template with Eleventy?

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

## CONTEXT:

- Eleventy and Nunjucks (and Markdown)
- A lot of long-form text (easier to create/edit using markdown).
- Complex layouts.
- Still new to SSGs

## GOAL:

- Manage chunks of text content using markdown.
- Use these markdown files with template partials.
- Assemble partials into a page.

## EXPECTED RESULT

Processed html page:

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <div>
          <p>Some content originating from a markdown file.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Some content originating from another markdown file.</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

---

## ATTEMPTED ACTIONS

Here is what I've tried so far...

(Note: I've excluded my base.njk (html doctype shell) for readability.)

### 1. NJK MAIN with NJK PARTIAL INCLUDES

#### INPUT

Directory Structure

```
src/
    /_includes
        base.njk
        _layout-A.njk
        _layout-B.njk
    main-layout.njk
    content-1.md
    content-2.md
```

main-layout.njk

```
    {% extends "base.njk" %}

    {% block content %}

        {% include '_layout-A.njk' %}

        {% include '_layout-B.njk' %}

    {% endblock %}
```

content-1.md

```
    ---
    layout: _layout-A.njk
    --- 
    Some content.
```

_layout-A.njk

```
    <div>{{ content | safe }}</div>
```

content-2.md

```
    ---
    layout: _layout-B.njk
    --- 

    Some more content.
```

_layout-B.njk

```
    <div>{{ content | safe }}</div>
```

#### RESULT

- Directory structure 'splits'.

```
dist/
    /content-1
        index.html
    /content-2
        index.html
    /main-layout
        index.html
```

- Markdown content not passed through to parent page. Empty child tags in parent.

main-layout/index.html

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <div></div>
        <div></div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

---

I'm at a loss for how the files are processed and what I can do to do what I set out to.

Comment: I'm honeslty confused as to what you are trying to do. Includes definitely work, but front matter will not be run with them, so when you included a child and it had a layout defined, it would not work like that. Can you simplify a bit?

Comment: @RaymondCamden My goal was to keep my content and layout as separate as possible. For example, I want to manage 'chunks' of textual content in markdown files and be able to mix and match those with different template partials for a given page. Lesha Ogonkov (below) confirmed what I had suspected; 11ty can't do it out of box - but can be with a little retooling. I'll clarify my post for any future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how 11ty works. Each MD file is a single page.

If you want to include multiple MD files to page, you should add custom filter for 11ty, to render it to html.

See examples in this issue https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/658

Comment: I added my solution to the issue listed above:

https://www.11ty.dev/docs/plugins/render/#usage